# How to generate ephemeral_keys in Stripe payment Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am implementing Stripe payment for my android application.
I download Stripe payment SDK example but I getting one error "https://hidden-beach-12345.herokuapp.com/ephemeral_keys" every time.
I don't know how can I generate an ephemeral key from stripe?

Answer (score -1):

This is covered in details in Stripe's documentation for their Android SDK [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard#prepare-your-api).

The idea is that you need an endpoint on your server that the SDK will hit to fetch an ephemeral key for a given customer. Your code, server-side, will create that ephemeral key in the language you're familiar with such as PHP or Ruby.